# Agregar items cuando se escribe en input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Como puedo hacer para agregar a través de un `botón` el texto que se escribe en el **input**, este debe agregar en la parte inferior del **input** ya sea creando un `input` dinámico y agregarle un estado disabled mediante `Jquery` o `Javascript`, no se como hacerlo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <title>Example</title>

    <!-- CDN Bootstrap 4 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- CSS  -->
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- CDN Jquery -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Qué es lo que haz intentado? deberías poner tu código JS.

Comment: @VickMuñoz Es que no se como hacerlo, que me recomiendas tu o planteas :(, estoy perdido

Comment: Requieres que se vaya agregando 1x1 o que se reescriba el nombre del usuario?

Comment: @VickMuñoz Agregando 1x1 abajo del input que luego se van a enviar con el formulario estos textos que se van agregando

Comment: ya quedo listo lo que solicitas.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes crear un arreglo de usuarios para luego poder enviarlo a tu controlador y alli poder recorrer ese array:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Example</title>

    <!-- CDN Bootstrap 4 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

   <!-- CDN Jquery -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script >
    function eliminar(correlativo){
        $('#fila'+correlativo).remove();

    }
    var correlativo=0;
    function miFuncion(){
        correlativo++;
        var username = $('#username').val();
        var myLabel = $('#miLabel');
        $('#tableUsuario').append("<tr id='fila"+correlativo+"'><td> <input type='hidden' name='arrayUsername[row"+correlativo+"][usuario]' value="+username+"/> <p>"+username+"</p></td><td><button  onClick='eliminar("+correlativo+")'>Eliminar</button></td></tr>");
    }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="username"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="miFuncion()">Agregar</button>
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <table id="tableUsuario" class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>usuario</th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>

                
            </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Si ves va dentro de un input tipo hidden que si quieres editarlo con otro boton solo debes quitarse esa propiedad para mostrarlo editable

Comment: Puedes hacer de que exista como un botón al lado que permita eliminar lo que se ha agregado?

Comment: @zerokira edite mi respuesta para agregar ese boton

Comment: voy agregarlo a mi código creo que me ha de servir, gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Espero te funcione creo los inputs y los deshabilito para que no puedan ser modificados.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('agregar');
var user = document.getElementById('name');
var contenedor = document.getElementById('almacenar');

var contador = 0;

btn.addEventListener('click',function(){

if(user.value == ""){ //si no ingresa nada en el input le manda mensaje de que ingrese un nombre
  alert('ingresa un nombre de usuario');
  return false;
}else{

  contador++;
 
 console.log(contador);

   var input = document.createElement('input');//creo elemento input y le creo un salto de línea
   var salto = document.createElement('br');
   var btn_eliminar = document.createElement('button');
   btn_eliminar.innerText= "Eliminar";
   btn_eliminar.type = 'button';
   btn_eliminar.id = "btn"+contador;
   input.type = 'text';
   input.id = "input"+contador;
   input.name = 'btn'+contador;
   input.value = user.value;
   input.setAttribute('disabled',''); // propiedad disabled
   contenedor.append(salto);//todo lo agrego al div de almacenar
   contenedor.append(input);
   contenedor.append(btn_eliminar);
   console.log(input);
    console.log(btn_eliminar);
  
  var botones = document.getElementById('btn'+contador);
  
  botones.addEventListener('click', function(){
     
    var btn_id = document.getElementById(this.id);
    
    var input_name = document.querySelector('input[name='+this.id+']');
       contenedor.removeChild(btn_id);
       contenedor.removeChild(input_name);
       contenedor.removeChild(salto);
  
  });
  
}


});
```

```html
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <title>Example</title>

    <!-- CDN Bootstrap 4 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- CSS  -->
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- CDN Jquery -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
        <div id="almacenar"></div>
        <button type="button" id="agregar" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Se tiene que crear una función donde al dar `click` en el botón mandamos llamar a la misma, le asigne un id al `input` para poder tomar su valor, después se crea un párrafo y le insertamos el valor del `input`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <title>Example</title>

    <!-- CDN Bootstrap 4 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- CSS  -->
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- CDN Jquery -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <script>
  function agregar(){
 var valor = document.getElementById("texto");
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("input-group");
  
  if (valor.value !== "") {
   input.value = valor.value;
    input.disabled = "true";
    inputs[0].appendChild(input); 
    valor.value = "";
    
  }
}
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input id="texto" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="agregar();">Agregar</button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

EDITADO: Se agrego el `input` `disabled`, ya quedaría de tu lado aplicar el estilo correspondiente.

Comment: puedes hacerlo para que cree un input debajo con un disabled y un button al lado que diga eliminar?

Comment: En lugar del <p> o en conjunto?

Comment: En lugar de <p>, la idea es que se cree un input disabled y al lado un boton de eliminar para eliminar ese input

Comment: Edite mi respuesta